# I am doing a project on robotic surgeries! Can anyone help me and give me some details related to this topic?

Tags: sensors, robotic-arm, automatic

Can anyone help me, because I am doing a project on robotical surgeries and I would like someone to help me and advise me. I wonder if anyone could give me some data on tests he or she has run in a surgical robot... Thank you for your attention!
Anything else will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant amount of information on this site: (http://allaboutroboticsurgery.com/surgicalrobots.html)

 That should give you the history and details about the past and current devices. 
Which should hopefully allow you to fine tune your questions to get more detailed specific answers.  Good Luck. -Frank

Comment: I know already this site , i am looking for something more proffesional and special.I need data and test results